# Is is possible to export a tensorflow dataset to file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using a tensorflow dataset to read a CSV file from disk. I'm filtering values using the dataset filter function. I would like to export the filtered dataset to disk just so that I can verify that the filtering is happening the way I intended. Does any one know a quick way to do this, or have any other suggestions on how to verify this logic.

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on what the format of the output data is. Generally pandas dataframes is a good way to read and write csv files. If you can update your question with examples of input vs output then I can provide a concrete example

Comment: Thanks @geekonedge. I have worked with pandas dataframes before, and found them very helpful. In this case I'm using tensorflow dataframes, and trying to inspect some intermediate values from tensors. I think I probably just need to work on improving my tensorflow skills in general and grokking the tensor model.

Comment: I see. I am not aware of any TF API function that allows you to write a tensor to csv. Generally you have to convert it to pandas or numpy format. There is a decode_csv function found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py) that might be helping in writing your own encode_csv function.

Comment: I think the easy solution is the read the file into a Pandas dataframe and do my filtering there. The dataset is not that big and I can fit it into memory.

Comment: Will [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset?version=nightly) tensorflow dataset library solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset()` function to filter the values. `filter()` class method Filters this dataset according to predicate

Sample code below

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x: x < 3)
list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
```

Output

```
[1,2]
```